# Make argument compulsory or optional base on calling method

Tags: c#, function, methods, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a this method

```
public void downloadAndSendFile(string fileType,
                                bool IsSendMail = false, 
                                string toEmail = "", 
                                string subject = "")
{
}
```

I want to do this,

- if the user passes `IsSendMail = true` while calling this method, then `toEmail` and `subject` arguments are compulsory

Comment: Why can't you use `if-else` blocks to check and validate this?

Comment: for if else block it require to pass SendMail, toEmail="", subject="" . i dont want to do this type of thing while calling method

Answer (score 2):

What about using 2 overloads of the method instead?

```
public void downloadAndSendFile(string fileType)
```

and

```
public void downloadAndSendFile(string fileType,
                            string toEmail, 
                            string subject)
```

My reasoning behind this is that you don't need the `IsSendMail` parameter at all. All it indicates is whether there will be 2 more arguments in the method call. If that's all it does, why not remove it and do different things depending on the parameters passed in instead? If you need the value of `IsSendMail` inside the method, you can assume that it is true in the second overload, and false in the first overload.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void downloadAndSendFile(string fileType,
                            bool IsSendMail, 
                            string toEmail, 
                            string subject)
{
  if(IsSendMail)
  {
      ... code ... 
    Console.WriteLine(toEmail + subject);
  }
  else
 {
      ... code ... 
  }
}
```